# Elegant way to chunk data using modulo?

Tags: python, modulo

Let's say I have 3 IDs:
`ids = ["x1", "y1", "z1"]`

I have a corresponding `for-loop` that generates another set of IDs to associate to each of these. I want `1,000,000` auto-generated IDs to be associated to x1, y1 and z1 respectively. Assume each comment in the below snippet is responsible for generating a UUID and inserting into a map where the value is a list, etc. Those details are not important.

#### Example:

```
for x in range(0, 3000000):
    if (x < 1000000):
       # associate this auto-generated ID to x1
    if (x >= 1000000 and x < 2000000):
       # associate this auto-generated ID to y1
    if (x >= 2000000 and x < 3000000):
       # associate this auto-generated ID to z1
```

I was trying to think of a clean way to do this with simple modulo arithmetic, but not quite remembering what I should do in this case.

Comment: This isn't modular. It would be modular if you associated `0, 3, 6, 9, ...` with `x1`, `1, 4, 7, 10, ...` with `x2`, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a list of lists with the corresponding ids at the same indexes (ids associated to x1 in first position, y1 in second ...), you can do :

```
IDS = [[], [], []]
for x in range(0,3000000):
    IDS[x//1000000].append(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing isn't related to modular arithmetic, since you're grouping all of them together, not rotating among the IDs.

```
for x in range(0, 1000000):
    # associate `x` with `x1`
for x in range(1000001, 2000000):
    # associate `x` with `y1`
for x in range(2000001, 3000000):
    # associate x with `z1`
```